# JSON and passing a URL value as a parameter - Chrome Extension

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, jsonp, parameter-passing

Ok, this is my final tango with this. Below I've listed the code. I'm able to get the value of the url and display it on screen for the current (active tab) in Google Chrome. Now all I have to do is pass that value as a parameter in the URL via JSON.  My processing file resides on a our remote server - in php. Everything I've done with respect to this has worked to perfection. However, any attempts to pass the current url or any url as one of the parameters - e.g. ?format=json&url=http://something.com&callback=? - results in nothing. I'm not sure if what I'm doing is wrong or if it is even possible. The important thing to note is that all we are looking to do is pass the url to a remote server for storage, processing etc and send back results. I have everything working but I just can't seem to get the url to pass as a parameter.

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <title>API JSON Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"  
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", windowLoaded, false);
        function windowLoaded() {
          chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
            document.getElementById('currentLink').innerHTML = tab.url;
          });
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

   var timeService =
       "http://api.ulore.com/api2.php?key=abce&url="+tab.url+"&format=json&callback=?";


    $.getJSON(timeService, function(data) {
    $('#showdata').html("<p>url_results="+data.post.url+"</p>");
              });
        });
    </script>
        <div id="showdata"></div>
</head>
<body>

</body>
    </html>
```

Again, all the JSON works fine when I'm testing other code. Even if I put in a NON-URL value as a parameter for url=..... it throws the appropriate error. However, it will not accept a URL for some reason.

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ethan-Anthony

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding and decoding the url.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

http://phpjs.org/functions/rawurlencode:501